# threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory

Tags: java, spring, apache-spark, kotlin, google-cloud-storage

Running into this exception every time I run my app with both **GoogleCloudStorage** and **Spark** installed:

*Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory*

Google cloud storage

```
<groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.0</version>
```

Apache Spark

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

(If I remove either one of them, the app runs fine)

I've tried:

- installing different versions of both
- Excluding Jackson from both com.fasterxml.jackson.core and installing dependencies individually

What else could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory` is from an old version of Jackson. Jackson uses `com.fasterxml` now. So you have some dependency depending on the older version, but at the same time are adding the newer version. You'll have either 1) to use the older version which some of your dependencies require 2) upgrade your dependencies to a newer version that uses the newer jackson (if possible), or 3) (advanced) isolate your dependencies through some means (loading them in separate classloaders/Java 9 modules, for instance).

`mvn dependency:tree` will give you more information so you can know what the problematic dependencies are.